# Escape Sequence's inconsistent behavior

Tags: java, escaping

I am curious as to why escape sequencing evaluates to different results in different situations.

```
public class EscapeChars{

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String sequence = args[0];
        System.out.println(sequence);
    }
}
```

Input `"//\\"`
Output `//\` - This is expected, given that the sequence `"\\"` evaluates to `\`

Input `"\\//"`
Output `\\//` - Going by my understanding of escape sequencing, I expected the output to be `\//` instead.

I want to understand the reason for this apparent inconsistent result.

Comment: Are you talking about the command in the shell?

Answer (score 0):

If you try this code:

```
System.out.println("\/");
```

You will get a compilation error( I tested with jdk 1.8 ).
The error says: illegal escape character.
Which means "/" is invalid.
Since you are input the sequence at runtime, so this may be the reason of showing the result as it was inputted.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, your java program is just printing the argument that was passed to it by the shell, or whatever program executed it, so at the time it is printed, the escape sequences have already bean processed, so it's not a java issue.